# MeteorJS Error invoking Method 'insertLesson': Method 'insertLesson' not found [404]

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I have a form that on submit calls a method 'insertLesson' and it seems to work fine and console.log what I want it to console.log. But after the console.log statement it is giving me the error 'Error invoking Method 'insertLesson': Method 'insertLesson' not found [404]'

Here is my form handling:

```
Template.body.events({
'submit .lesson-plan'(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let title = e.target.title.value;
    let content = e.target.content.value;
    Meteor.call('insertLesson',title,content);
}

});
```

Here is my insertLesson Method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    insertLesson: function(title,content){
        console.log(title);
        console.log(content);
        console.log('pre submitted')
    }
});
```

and if I type "foo" in the title and "bar" in the content. My console will show:

foo
bar
Error invoking Method 'insertLesson': Method 'insertLesson' not found [404]

**EDIT:**

### Solution

I hadn't realized I also had to import the the file where I declared a new Mongo.collection to my server side ... so in my server/main.js I now have the line:

```
import '../imports/api/lessons'
```

and everything is working

Answer (score 1):

server/main.js must import the file where you declare the new mongo collection:

import '../imports/api/lessons'